# How to print an arrow pattern like this

Tags: c

I need to input an odd number between `10~16`, and print picture like the one shown below. I think I know how to make a loop to print the numbers in the arrow, but I just can't tell how to align the numbers.

(English isn't my native language, please don't told off for my grammar.)

Can anyone tell me how to make a loop or tell me how to align? Thank you!

This is the expected output:

[image]

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;
int i,j;


int main(){
    printf("(n): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int multiplier = n/2+1;
    printf("    ");
    for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){
    
        printf(" %d ",i);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    for(i=1;i<(n/2)+2;i++){
        printf("%d ",i);
        multiplier = multiplier - i +1;
        for(j=1;j<(i*2);j++){;
            printf(" %2d ",multiplier*i);
            multiplier = multiplier+1;
        }
    printf("\n");
    multiplier = n/2+1;
    }
    
    for(i=7;i<n+1;i++){
        printf("%d ",i);
        multiplier = 5;
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%d ",multiplier*i);
            multiplier += 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image]

I need to align them to make those numbers look like the first photo.

Comment: You need to think about what you're doing.  For example, `printf(" %d ",i);` is obviously a mistake.  Why?  Because you require a fixed-width for all numbers.  But this will use a different width for a 1-digit vs. 2-digit value.  So you're lost already.  Instead, use `printf(" %2d", i);`  That will pad all numbers to 2 digits.  If you need more than two digits, then use a larger field width (possibly a variable field width).  Then, to add padding for an empty field, just use that many spaces.  Again, reason it out.

Comment: Hint: to print `n` spaces you can try `printf("%.*s", n, "");` ... there are **many** variations you can use though!

Comment: I think you meant printf("%*s", n, ""); to display n spaces. The dot variation would be used to display n characters (say stars or spaces) and look like printf("%.*s", n, "********"); where the last field contains the max number of the character -- in this example 8 stars.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// set based on the digit count of your numbers
#define SPACE "   " 
#define FORMAT "%3d"

int n;
int i,j,k;


int main(){
    printf("(n): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int multiplier = n/2+1;
    printf(SPACE);
    for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){
    
        printf(FORMAT,i);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    for(i=1;i<(n/2)+2;i++){
        printf(FORMAT,i);
        multiplier = multiplier - i +1;
        for(k=0;k<n/2-i+1;k++){
            printf(SPACE);
        }
        for(j=1;j<(i*2);j++){
            
            printf(FORMAT,multiplier*i);
            multiplier = multiplier+1;
        }
    printf("\n");
    multiplier = n/2+1;
    }
    
    for(i=7;i<n+1;i++){
        printf(FORMAT,i);
        for(k=0;k<n/2-1;k++){
            printf(SPACE);
        }
        multiplier = 5;
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf(FORMAT,multiplier*i);
            multiplier += 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}
```

**Explanation**: The logic of your code remains the same, the only difference is, when you print any number, *always* use a fixed number of characters via formated strings (3 characters if the maximum number is 2-digit, 4 characters if the maximum number is 3-digit etc.) This way, all the numbers you print will be aligned. Now, to achieve the arrow shape, you just print a certain number of blank characters. For the upper part of the arrow, you print `n/2 - i + 1` strings (each containing the same number of blank characters as the character count used when printing the numbers), where `i` is the row index. (This is best understood with an example: if `n` is 11, for the top of the arrow, you firstly print 5 blank strings, then you print the number at the top, for the next row, you print 4 blank strings, then the numbers etc. Each row requires printing one blank field less and that's why we add `- i`.) As for the bottom part of the arrow, you just print a fixes amount of blank strings before printing the numbers, which is `n/2 - 1` if you want the bottom part to be three numbers wide.

If you need to figure out the digit count automatically, instead of defining `SPACE` and `FORMAT`, you can also do this (though I think it's too much):

```c
int highestNumber = n * multiplier;
int numSpaces = (int)log10(highestNumber) + 2;
char format[10], space[10];
sprintf(format, "%%%dd", numSpaces);
for(i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
    space[i] = ' ';
space[numSpaces]=0;
```

This does basically the same thing, only the `format` and the `space` strings are determined by the algorithm based on the digit count of the maximum number in the series (thr number in the right corner of the top part of the arrow). The simplest way to get the digit count is using a logarithm.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` what happens if the user slips and types `"q3"` by accident instead of `"13"`? Is the remaining operation of your program well-defined?

Answer (score 1):

> *but I just can't tell how to align the numbers.*

The easiest way would be to think of it as a matrix of size `n x n`.
Initialize this matrix with all zero's and then fill the appropriate cells of this matrix with product of `row` index and `column` index. Once done, print this matrix. While printing special care need to be taken for the cells whose value is `0`, instead of printing `0`, print space in place of `0`.

Now the only question remain is -
How to identify the appropriate cells in the matrix which can form arrow shape?

Here is the logic -

User is suppose to enter odd number in range `10 - 16` i.e. the valid input is anyone of these values - `11`, `13` and `15`.
Whichever the valid value (within the given range) user give as input (say `N`), find the `mid` of range from `0` to `N` - add `1` to `N` and divide by `2`.
Starting from row `1` to row `mid`, for each row, the range (columns) to fill is `mid + row - 1` and `mid + row + 1` and in the rest of the rows (from row `mid + 1` to row `N`), just fill range (columns) from `mid - 1` to `mid + 1`. Note that the value to be filled is the product of current `row` index and `column` index of matrix.

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MX 16    // maximum size of matrix (as per OP)

void print_matrix (int len, int m[MX][MX]) {
    char str[5];
    for (int r = 0; r <= len; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c <= len; ++c) {
            // If cell value is 0 then print space otherwise 
            // print value of cell
            char * fmtst = m[r][c] ? "%d" : "%c";
            snprintf (str, 5, fmtst, m[r][c] ? m[r][c] : ' ');

            // Right aligned output
            printf ("%4s", str);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

int main (void) {
    int m[MX][MX] = {0};   // Initialize matrix with 0
    int N = 0;
    int done = 0;

    // Take input from user
    do {
        printf ("Enter any one of these values - [11, 13, 15]: \n");
        scanf ("%d", &N);
        if ((N == 11) || (N == 13) || (N == 15)) {
            done = 1;
        } else {
            int c;
            while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                /* discard characters, if any */;
            printf ("Invalid input.. try again..\n");
        }

    } while (!done);

    // Find out mid
    int mid = (N + 1) / 2;

    // Prepare the matrix

    // Fill the first row and first column with the value of index
    for (int i = 0; i < (N + 1); ++i) {
        m[i][0] = i;
        m[0][i] = i;
    }

    // Fill rest of the matrix
    for (int row = 1; row <= (N + 1); ++row) {
        int x = row - 1;

        if (row <= mid) {
            x = row - 1;
        } else {
            x = 1;
        }

        int min = mid - x;
        int max = mid + x;

        for (int col = min; col <= max; ++col) {
            m[row][col] = row * col;
        }
    }

    // Matrix prepared, print it
    print_matrix (N, m);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 
Enter any one of these values - [11, 13, 15]: 
11
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
   1                       6                    
   2                  10  12  14                
   3              12  15  18  21  24            
   4          12  16  20  24  28  32  36        
   5      10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50    
   6   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66
   7                  35  42  49                
   8                  40  48  56                
   9                  45  54  63                
  10                  50  60  70                
  11                  55  66  77                

# ./a.out 
Enter any one of these values - [11, 13, 15]: 
15
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
   1                               8                            
   2                          14  16  18                        
   3                      18  21  24  27  30                    
   4                  20  24  28  32  36  40  44                
   5              20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60            
   6          18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72  78        
   7      14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98    
   8   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96 104 112 120
   9                          63  72  81                        
  10                          70  80  90                        
  11                          77  88  99                        
  12                          84  96 108                        
  13                          91 104 117                        
  14                          98 112 126                        
  15                         105 120 135
```

If you want to avoid the matrix, you can. Print the first `row` first and then you just need to do a few modification around the part of code (nested `for` loop in `main()`) where matrix is filled. Column `0` values are current row index. Add one loop above the nested `for` loop to print the spaces from column `1` to `min - 1`, after this instead of writing values to matrix, print them and add another loop after the nested `for` loop to print spaces from column `max + 1` to `N`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't easy to follow. The variable names, the `+2` sometimes, and its *density* make it difficult to read.

Below is a very simple solution using your 3 values to produce the 3 arrows. Taking and verifying user input is left as an exercise.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrow( int n ) {
    int r, c; // row and col

    for( c = 0; c <= n; c++ ) // header + all required cols
        printf( "%4.0d", c ); // magic explained below
    putchar( '\n' );

    int m = (n+1)/2, lm = m, rm = m; // "middle" = "left middle" = "right middle"

    // lm-- and rm++ widen the # of cols to print on each row
    for( r = 1; r <= m; r++, lm--, rm++ ) { // "arrow head" rows only
        printf( "%4d", r ); // row index
        for( c = 1; c <= rm; c++ ) // all required columns
            printf( "%4.0d", c < lm ? 0 : r*c ); // explained below
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    for( lm = m-1, rm = m+1; r <= n; r++ ) { // arrow's "shaft" rows
        printf( "%4d", r ); // row index continues to increment
        for( c = 1; c <= rm; c++ ) // required columns
            printf( "%4.0d", c < lm ? 0 : r*c ); // left cols are blank, otherwise...
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    arrow( 11 ); putchar( '\n' ); // self-explanatory
    arrow( 13 ); putchar( '\n' );
    arrow( 15 ); putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
   1                       6
   2                  10  12  14
   3              12  15  18  21  24
   4          12  16  20  24  28  32  36
   5      10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
   6   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66
   7                  35  42  49
   8                  40  48  56
   9                  45  54  63
  10                  50  60  70
  11                  55  66  77

       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
   1                           7
   2                      12  14  16
   3                  15  18  21  24  27
   4              16  20  24  28  32  36  40
   5          15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55
   6      12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
   7   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91
   8                      48  56  64
   9                      54  63  72
  10                      60  70  80
  11                      66  77  88
  12                      72  84  96
  13                      78  91 104

       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
   1                               8
   2                          14  16  18
   3                      18  21  24  27  30
   4                  20  24  28  32  36  40  44
   5              20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
   6          18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72  78
   7      14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98
   8   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96 104 112 120
   9                          63  72  81
  10                          70  80  90
  11                          77  88  99
  12                          84  96 108
  13                          91 104 117
  14                          98 112 126
  15                         105 120 135
```

The "magic" of `printf( "%4.0d", ...` is that `printf()` will output a field as wide as requested (4). However, the `precision` (`.0`) will not output the value if it is `0`. Therefore, a conditional expression determines if the product of row x col should be calculated and printed or should the value `0` be used (making a blank gap as wide as if it were a printed number.)

With the above, the problem can be solved with very little code. It's somewhat wasteful of computing resources, but the problem is, after all, just a toy.

---

**EDIT:**
Having preached the principle of **DRY**, it's embarrassing to have posted code that isn't. Here's a better version. Output is the same.

```
void arrow( int n ) {
    int r, c;

    for( r = 0; r <= n; r++ )
        printf( "%4.0d", r );
    putchar( '\n' );

    int m = (n+1)/2, lm = m, rm = m;

    for( r = 1; r <= n; r++ ) {
        printf( "%4d", r );
        for( c = 1; c <= rm; c++ )
            printf( "%4.0d", c < lm ? 0 : r*c );
        putchar( '\n' );
        lm = r < m ? lm - 1 : m - 1;
        rm = r < m ? rm + 1 : m + 1;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT #2**
An alternative perception of the problem is that of generating a raster graphic; in this case, an arrow whose pixels are calculated numbers.

Below is a small bitmap graphic routine. The tedious labour of determining the bit pattern would be repaid by making the output routine more sophisticated. Not all graphics can be generated by calculations (like the "arrow" challenge.) Here's a start:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void smiles( void ) {
    uint16_t sm[] = {
        0x0000, 0x03C0, 0x0C30, 0x1008, 0x2004, 0x2664, 0x4662, 0x4002,
        0x4812, 0x4422, 0x23C4, 0x2004, 0x1008, 0x0C30, 0x03C0, 0x0000,
    };

    for( int r = 0; r < 16; r++ ) {
        for( ; sm[r]; sm[r] >>= 1 )
            printf( "%c ", " X"[sm[r]&1] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    smiles();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
            X X X X
        X X         X X
      X                 X
    X                     X
    X     X X     X X     X
  X       X X     X X       X
  X                         X
  X     X             X     X
  X       X         X       X
    X       X X X X       X
    X                     X
      X                 X
        X X         X X
            X X X X
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to consider is a single loop over the rows and then a single loop over the columns to output your needed *Arrow* representation of values. In each the loop over the rows and then columns you use a simple `if() .. else` to check the state of the loop and output either the heading or row prefix before outputting the spaces or values.

Additionally, there is no need to loop further than the last value in each row. Simply terminate your output loop after the last value in each row is printed.

Rather than taking input from the user on `stdin`, it is often more convenient to provide the needed information as a program argument. That way you need only press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once and you can simply scroll back through your command-history to run the program again with the same argument without having to retype the value each time.

Putting it altogether, and using only 2-loops, you can do something similar to the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* simple function to convert s to int and store at address of n,
 * returns 1 if n one of 11, 13 or 15, 0 otherwise.
 */
int get_reqd_n (const char *s, int *n)
{
  /* if s NULL or points to invalid integer representation, handle error */
  if (!s || sscanf (s, "%d", n) != 1) {
    fputs ("error: argument not one of (11, 13, 15)\n"
           "usage: ./program n   (n one of 11, 13, 15)\n", stderr);
    return 0;
  }
  
  /* check n is one of 11, 13, 15 */
  if (!(*n == 11 || *n == 13 || *n == 15)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid argument '%d', not one of (11, 13, 15)\n"
                     "usage: ./program n   (n one of 11, 13, 15)\n", *n);
    return 0;
  }
  
  return 1;   /* return success */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  int n = 0,                          /* 11, 13 or 15 from 1st argument */
      mid = 0,                        /* midpoint value */
      values = 0;                     /* values to print with mid */
  
  if (!get_reqd_n (argv[1], &n)) {    /* validate n is one of 11, 13, 15 */
    return 1;
  }
  mid = (n + 1) / 2;                  /* set midpoint value */
  
  printf ("n: %d\n", n);
  
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {      /* loop header and each row */
    if (i) {                          /* if 2nd row+, print row no. */
      printf ("%4d", i);
    }
    else {                            /* otherwise no row no. for 1st row */
      fputs ("    ", stdout);
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {     /* loop each number column */
      if (!i) {                       /* if 1st row, print heading */
        printf ("%4d", j + 1);
      }
      else {  /* otherwise - arrow rows */
        if (j > mid - 2 + values) {   /* if all values printed, break loop */
          break;
        }
        else if (j < mid - values) {  /* if before values, print spaces */
          fputs ("    ", stdout);
        }
        else {  /* otherwise print value */
          printf ("%4d", i * (j + 1));
        }
      }
    }
    putchar ('\n');   /* tidy each row with newline */
    
    /* while less than mid, increment values, otherwise set to 2 */
    values = i < mid ? values + 1 : 2;
  }
  
  (void)argc;   /* cast to avoid -Wunused warning on argc */
}
```

**Note:** since `argc` is not used in the program, simply casting to `(void)` will avoid the `-Wunused` warning. (you are compiling with full warnings enabled each time -- right?

**Example Use/Output**

For each of your odd values, `11`, `13`, and `15`, you would get:

```
$ ./bin/code-golf-arrow
n: 11
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
   1                       6
   2                  10  12  14
   3              12  15  18  21  24
   4          12  16  20  24  28  32  36
   5      10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
   6   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66
   7                  35  42  49
   8                  40  48  56
   9                  45  54  63
  10                  50  60  70
  11                  55  66  77


$ ./bin/code-golf-arrow 13
n: 13
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
   1                           7
   2                      12  14  16
   3                  15  18  21  24  27
   4              16  20  24  28  32  36  40
   5          15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55
   6      12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
   7   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91
   8                      48  56  64
   9                      54  63  72
  10                      60  70  80
  11                      66  77  88
  12                      72  84  96
  13                      78  91 104


$ ./bin/code-golf-arrow 15
n: 15
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
   1                               8
   2                          14  16  18
   3                      18  21  24  27  30
   4                  20  24  28  32  36  40  44
   5              20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
   6          18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72  78
   7      14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98
   8   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96 104 112 120
   9                          63  72  81
  10                          70  80  90
  11                          77  88  99
  12                          84  96 108
  13                          91 104 117
  14                          98 112 126
  15                         105 120 135
```

For any other number representation provided as an argument to the program you would get:

```
$ ./bin/code-golf-arrow 14
error: invalid argument '14', not one of (11, 13, 15)
usage: ./program n   (n one of 11, 13, 15)
```

Any non-integer representation entered results in the following:

```
$ ./bin/code-golf-arrow foo
error: argument not one of (11, 13, 15)
usage: ./program n   (n one of 11, 13, 15)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. There are always multiple ways to approach any problem in C. So long as you fully validate all input and handle any errors appropriately, the choice is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this problem is by thinking of a grid with rows and columns, and then figuring out how `i` and `j` are related. Once you understand that relationship, you can set some rules to solve the problem.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    // number is defined by user (should be odd and greater than 3)
    int number = 11;
    int k = number / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= number; j++){
            if ((k == j || k + 1 == j || k + 2 == j || k + 1 >= i) && (i + j >= k + 2 && j - i <= k))
                printf("%5d", i * j);
            else if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                printf("%5s", " ");
            else if (i == 0)
                printf("%5d", j);
            else if (j == 0)
                printf("%5d", i);
            else
                printf("%5s", " ");
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the explanation for number=7, k=3. Consider a grid with rows (i) and columns (j). Desired output is:

[image: grid]

Each condition with its specified area looks like below:
[image]